# How can I get this page with curl in php - fails weirdly for me every time

Tags: php, curl

When I try to use curl in php to get this page:

https://society6.com/hightonridley/collection/connoisseur-fine-art-studies-5779098

it never gets the page.

To get the curl to use, I visited the page in Chrome (I'm on a Mac) and used the developer tools to copy as cURL.

[image: how I got the cURL text]

I then visited [Code Beautify](https://codebeautify.org/curl-to-php-online) to convert that to php. When I execute the php the first time, in the $result (of the curl) I get a different page, this one:

https://society6.com/hightonridley

When I execute again, in the $result, I get an "oops something went wrong our end" page. Executing again and I get a "Sorry, this page doesn't exist" page back from Society6 in $result.

I'm at a loss to know what's going on. I can successfully use curl to get https://society6.com/hightonridley and also https://society6.com

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or what else I need to do, that would be fantastic.
Here is the php code I'm using:

```
// Generated @ codebeautify.org
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://society6.com/hightonridley/collection/connoisseur-fine-art-studies-5779098');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: society6.com';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: User-Continent=EU; User-Country=GB; _gcl_au=1.1.2089211169.1654939780; s6ses2=ceec7b25bfc26f1b0acf9a2aee4233c1; s6pool=control; _gid=GA1.2.273482383.1654939781; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=b0ee4c4e-60dd-4fdb-821f-333829c84f98; FPC=d91d7e2f-1da8-489d-970e-7cfaa0b1f9d0; bluecoreNV=false; __qca=P0-1722209504-1654939781390; _bcai_i=k41BVR_G2D-4YeDDBRHeD; _bcai_v=k41BVR_G2D-4YeDDBRHeD; _bcai_vs=COOKIE; _bcai_vn=_bcai_i; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU5qQmxOR0ZoTnpJdE9EVTNaQzAwWW1GbUxXRTBNRGt0WXpFMFpETTRaVE0xWTJFMg; _cq_duid=1.1654939782.zNrO0lc95hwUerVP; _cq_suid=1.1654939782.U17Keu9xQFpGPRGD; _scid=4f95c617-9a4c-4601-89c4-9d070f6c9c34; _fbp=fb.1.1654939782805.1990855742; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjCachedUserAttributes=eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7IlVzZXItQ29udGluZW50IjoiRVUiLCJVc2VyLUNvdW50cnkiOiJHQiJ9LCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGx9; btIdentify=d56d1950-46fd-4a03-c0ad-b1c8f382eb9c; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1654939783559r0.0725084660064601; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2022-06-11T09:29:44.728Z; _tkbl_check_cookie=true; tkbl_cvuuid=a5ac3c1c-22c7-4373-ad42-8822d9ac2304; _hjSessionUser_1419071=eyJpZCI6ImUwNjA1NmI3LTBiMzktNWFjNy1hMTQ0LTU1ZDM2MzgxNTIwMyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTQ5Mzk3ODI3ODYsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _ga_TR88PG3WYC=GS1.1.1654965377.4.1.1654965377.60; _ga=GA1.1.1459837331.1654939781; mp_dev_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217f6b17f7fad9b-0c028f175c6614-37677109-232800-17f6b17f7fbfea%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201654939780826%7D; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Sat+Jun+11+2022+17%3A36%3A18+GMT%2B0100+(British+Summer+Time)&version=6.4.0&hosts=&consentId=1918cbbe-d82e-486f-8efd-ec5e47753567&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&geolocation=GB%3BENG&AwaitingReconsent=false; _uetsid=063b29d0e96911ec93d74104381db76a; _uetvid=6cb35f309f1911ecad31a3f5f2458c8a; _bcai_lpv=5; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9UVZjUlA5czBhcURXWFBxd0U1c0pzRjQ1QmdqaTJ3b0ombj1renowX2dEZWZEdFJheXVMQVlkZ2VRJm09MSZ0PUFBQUFBR0treElRJnJtPTEmcnQ9QUFBQUFHS2t4SVE; _bti=%7B%22app_id%22%3A%22society6%22%2C%22bsin%22%3A%22pPvBJFz6VqZ1MftVAANuL5ccagF4qakkW0RAAXEbvfIl6pVQ7MJZ3YyQRzT6YrWXFd70jNvYlBwAJBYykZJhFw%3D%3D%22%2C%22is_identified%22%3Afalse%7D; rbuid=rbos-3364dae9-ecd6-4a51-81f5-54f48c6c85d2';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua: \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"102\"';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: \"macOS\"';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Start by posting here the actual code you're using that is misbehaving. Without that we're guessing.

Comment: I've added the code as per your guidance

Comment: Not sure if the multiple cookies are set correctly: You specify them like this (in one field, separated with `;`) when you use the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option, but in HTTP they are sent as multiple headers with the same name, so I would try to specify them differently - either use the proper option, or add one header per cookie.

Comment: I would say that the page you are accessing with CURL is JS heavy. CURL will download whatever there is, but it doesn't execute the JS for you, therefore probably not any useful information for you to grab from that page.

Comment: Cyberbrain: I didn't specify the code, Code Beautify did, so I'm going to assume it's ok syntactically.

@GuidoFaecke - I think that's it - thanks! I didn't think it through and of course the javascript isn't executed, as that's done by the browser.
Using echo to display $result executed the javascript out of context leading to what I described as weird behaviour.